# How to set "BINARY" to VARCHAR column definition for MySQL with django.models?

Tags: django

I have simple model following.

```
from django.db import models
class ItemAttr(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

converted to

```
CREATE TABLE `webapp_itemattr` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Now, I want to distinguish between uppercase and lowercase in "name" field. How do this? My goal is to get to following SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE `webapp_itemattr` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(255) BINARY NOT NULL,
    `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

apply ALTER TABLE SQL directly, it is work. but at django unit test, this MODIFY SQL is not applyed.

```
ALTER TABLE webapp_itemattr MODIFY name VARCHAR(255) BINARY NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can inherit from CharField and create you own field:

```
class CustomBinaryCharField(models.CharField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return super(CustomBinaryCharField, self).db_type(connection) + ' binary'
```

Here is a [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-model-fields/) to Django doc about custom fields.